# How to link 2 users together in firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My application is about taking care of elderly people, there are 2 type of users, elderly and watcher, the watcher is someone of elderly family that takes care of elderly.
In registration, the watcher will register himself then register the elderly, it requires email for both.
Then, the watcher will register the medication of elderly.
After that, the elderly have check when he take his medicine and a notification will send to watcher that the elderly has taken his medicine.

How can I link these 2 users in Firebase Cloud Firestore?
How can I let firebase know that this watcher is a watcher for this elderly in registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad... But here is some general "guidance":

- The information you can associate to a user via the [Firebase Authentication service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) is limited to a set of fields: email, phoneNumber, displayName, etc.
- If you want to add any extra information to a user, like **the link with another user**, or a physical address, the age, ... you should store that in any other storage services, like Google Cloud Firestore.

The [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#user_properties) actually indicates:

> Firebase users have a fixed set of basic properties—a unique ID, a
> primary email address, a name and a photo URL—stored in the project's
> user database, that can be updated by the user (iOS, Android, web).
> You cannot add other properties to the user object directly; instead,
> you can store the additional properties in any other storage services,
> like Google Cloud Firestore.

---

Your question:

> How can I link these 2 users in Firebase Cloud Firestore? How can I
> let Firebase know that this watcher is a watcher for this elderly in
> registration?

One usually creates a Firestore document for each user that is created in the Authentication service. The best is to use the user uid as the ID of the Firestore document, in such a way you can easily fetch this doc when the user signs-in.

For identifying the watcher-elderly relationship, it's difficult to answer without knowing the exact queries you plan to execute, but a straightforward approach would be to store the uid of the other "member of the couple" in each user doc.

Comment: the progress will be as follow: (sign up watcher page >> sign up elderly page) both of them are in collection('users'), and the doc id is the user id, both have field called 'userType', which is either 'watcher' or 'elderly', so how can I link them?

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer: "it's difficult to answer without knowing the exact queries you plan to execute, but a straightforward approach would be to store the uid of the other "member of the couple" in each user doc." You could have a field named `linkedUser` which contais the Id if the other usef.

Comment: what will be the query to add uid in linkedUser?, I need an examole please

Comment: I cannot answer, it depends on your app. If you know the two users to be linked you can write each user ID in each other user document.

Comment: I thought about this idea, in my application, the watcher will register first, and then the elderly, so how can I add the ID of elderly in watcher fields if the elderly account is not registered yet.

Comment: You need to find a way to materialize the link. Through the elderly email? Frankly, this is very business requirements oriented, I don't think I can help much more.